# inserting primary key of tbl1 into foreign key of tbl2 and primary key of tbl1, tbl2 into foreign key of tbl3

Tags: sql-server

```
 CREATE TABLE tbl1 as [departments]
 (
   deptId int identity primary key,
   deptName nvarchar(40)
 )

 CREATE TABLE tbl2 as [teachers]
 (
   teacherId int identity primary key,
   teacherName nvarchar(40),
   deptId int references departments
 )

CREATE TABLE tbl3 as [departmentChiefs]
(
  deptId int references departments,
  teacherId int references teachers,
  chiefDate date
)
```

I want to insert the primary key of (departments) table into foreign key of (teachers) table also inserting primary key of (departments and teachers) into foreign key of departmentChiefs

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you want to do? Are you want to insert one row in all your tables or maybe you want to create script for insert data from other source?

Comment: i want to insert teachers row and link to newly created departments row and define the chief for that department

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DeptId INT, @TeacherId INT;

INSERT INTO departments (deptName) VALUES ('My Department');
SELECT @DeptId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO teachers (teacherName, deptId) VALUES ('Joe Smith', @DeptId);
SELECT @TeacherId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO departmentChiefs (deptId, teacherId, chiefDate) VALUES (@DeptId, @TeacherId, GETDATE());
```

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the most recent identity value inserted in the current scope, and the result can be used as input into another `INSERT` statement. You might also want to do a little error checking before using it (make sure it's not `NULL` for example).